# Improve responsiveness and formatting of private beta launch announcement emails

Tags: bug, email, responsive-design, private-beta

Today I got an email announcing the private beta of [Programming Language Design and Implementation](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/). When opening it on the standard Mail app on my iPhone, it seems to be using only 60% of the available width, which makes it much longer than necessary. Also, the sign-up links could be formatted - the public launch announcement emails do have them.

[image]